# Macro for a structure

Tags: c, macros, struct

I have a structure

```
typedef struct lzma_next_coder_s lzma_next_coder;

struct lzma_next_coder_s {
lzma_coder *coder;
lzma_vli id;
uintptr_t init;
lzma_code_function code;
lzma_end_function end;
lzma_check (*get_check)(const lzma_coder *coder);
lzma_ret (*memconfig)(lzma_coder *coder, uint64_t *memusage,
        uint64_t *old_memlimit, uint64_t new_memlimit);
lzma_ret (*update)(lzma_coder *coder, lzma_allocator *allocator,
        const lzma_filter *filters,
        const lzma_filter *reversed_filters);
};
```

Following is the macro:

```
#define LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT \
(lzma_next_coder){ \
    .coder = NULL, \
    .init = (uintptr_t)(NULL), \
    .id = LZMA_VLI_UNKNOWN, \
    .code = NULL, \
    .end = NULL, \
    .get_check = NULL, \
    .memconfig = NULL, \
    .update = NULL, \
}
```

This is the call

`lzma_next_coder *next;`

`next = LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT;` `line 210`.

Main aim is to initialize the `next` structure with NULL.

But I am getting `error C2059: syntax error : '{'` and `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'` at line 210

I am using Visual studio 2010 to compile. I guess VS doesn't recognize `.coder=NULL` style syntax. I also wrote a function(instead of the macro) in which I initialize the structure members with NULL like this.

```
lzma_next_coder make_null_lzma()
{
lzma_next_coder temp;
temp.coder = NULL;
    //other members
    return temp;
}
next = make_null_lzma();
```

The errors go away now but I am getting run-time crash. Am I doing it correctly? Is next really getting initialized with NULL? Or have I messed it up?

Thanks

Comment: `c { .a = 0, .b = 2 }` since when is this valid syntax?

Comment: Even if it were the only problem in your code (which it is not), VS does not support C99, i.e., it does not support designated initializers like you have there. @NiklasR: Since C99...

Comment: Since C99 it has been valid.

Comment: Ty, g2k. Never seen before. @Capricorn: what about `*next = {0};`? Or a function `lzma_next_coder_init(next);`

Comment: @NiklasR: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: If you use designated initializers, all unspecified fields will be initialized to 0 (which is `NULL` for pointers).  So `foo x = { .a = NULL, .b = NULL };` is redundant, you can just say `foo x = { .a = NULL };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that `LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT` is used to initialize a structure, whereas `next` is a *pointer to* a structure. To initialize it to NULL simply do:

```
next = NULL
```

In addition, Visual C++ wouldn't support this kind of initialization anyway, as it was introduced in C99, which isn't supported by Visual Studio. To get around this limitation you can replace the macro with a C90-style initialization:

```
#define LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT \
{ \
    NULL, \
    LZMA_VLI_UNKNOWN, \
    (uintptr_t)(NULL), \
    NULL, \
    NULL, \
    NULL, \
    NULL, \
    NULL, \
}
```

Note that in the fields have been rearranged to match the order of the struct.

*EDIT:* This only works when initializing a structure. If you want to assign to an already existing structure, you can create a temporary and assign it to the old struct. For example:

```
{
  tmp lzma_next_coder_s tmp = LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT;
  old = tmp;
}
```

Comment: `next = NULL` gives `error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` `could be 'lzma_next_coder_s &lzma_next_coder_s::operator =(const lzma_next_coder_s &)'` Also, the second part doesn't work either

Comment: If the first part doesn't work, the type of `next` in the question is most likely wrong (is it really a `*`). Also, this only works when initializing a struct. See edits in answer for a way to get around this.

Comment: It is really a `*` Please see my previous comment below. Will this work?

Comment: @Capricorn, if it really is a pointer, and you want to assign it like `name = ...`, then all you can do is to assign it to a pointer. However, if you assign it like `*next = ...` then you assign whatever `next` points to. Yes, in that case the above will work, but you have to use `*next` rather than `old` in the example above.

Comment: `lzma_next_coder_s tmp = LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT; next = tmp;` This works great. But I don't get it. Why can't I directly do `next = LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT;` and the `LZMA_NEXT_CODER_INIT` macro as defined above by you

Comment: @Capricorn: Because this is not supported by the C90 standard. You can initialize a new instance of a structure, and you can copy between two objects, that's it. In C99, *compound literals* was introduced using the syntax `(name){ ... }`, this allow you to create temporary object of a specific struct type, which you can, for example, pass to functions or assign to other structs.

Answer (score 4):

The error messages are formatted as if they come from MSVC.  MSVC does not support C99; the constructs you are using are in C99 and not C89 which is all MSVC supports.

You'll either need to find a C99 compiler (which suggests using a GCC compiler  such as Cygwin or MinGW) or forego the convenience of the compound literal and designated initializers.

The function version should work fine.  You could check that you've initialized everything by printing out the initialized structure.  I'm assuming that there is some other code between the function definition and its use in the assignment to `temp`.

Comment: I tried `next = make_null_lzma(&next);` `lzma_next_coder make_null_lzma(lzma_next_coder *temp)
{
 temp->coder = NULL; return *temp; }` This compiles fine but I don't know if its correct.

Comment: This is the same as `next.coder = NULL`. Hard to tell if this is correct, as it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I want to make next structure members initialize to NULL. Thats all